# Missing separate debuginfos

Tags: c++, debugging, centos, gdb, redhat

I am debugging a coredump file from the production environment(two environment, not the same), I input "gdb [programe name] core.xxx then bt" but it hint like the title and pic below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDmqx.png)
There are question masks at the top of the stack and I can't find where the Segmentation fault generated
Kernel Version: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muTgQ.png)
Linux Version: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUK57.png)

System compiled from executable file：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm2PL.png)
(Note :Source code and executable program are not in the same system)

I want to find a way to know where did the segment error occur, I'd appreciate it if you could help me !

I have installed some missing rpm libraries according to the prompts but still not work：
glibc-debuginfo-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm
ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686.rpm
libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm
kernel-debug-debuginfo-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64.rpm
kernel-debuginfo-common-x86_64-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Your first screenshot already tells you that it crashes at a `memset` call in PackHandle.cpp line 544.

Comment: I have found where the crash happen and solved this problem(related to the crash info) but still not find a way how to remove these question marks，but thank you for your answer !

Comment: Is this `libclntsh` coming from you? Are you compiling it?

Comment: No, this is a system library that comes whit CentOS.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My OS CentOS 7.9

> Missing separate `debuginfos`, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64 libconfig-1.4.9-5.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64

1. You need to modify the `enable=1` of the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo` (CentOS 7) or the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Debuginfo.repo`(CentOS 8)
2. Use `sudo yum install glibc` to install
3. `yum install yum-utils`
4. Use `yum debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64` to install.

Hope this help.